# Hide all elements with a z-index less than 1

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Im trying to write a jquery code which hides all elements which have a z-index of less than 1. I haven't the slightest idea where to start.

Answer (score 3):

```
("*").filter(function() {
    var zindex = $(this).css("z-index");
    return (zindex !== undefined) && zindex < 1;
}).hide();
```

Comment: @DavidThomas I don't think z-index can be anything but a number. However, I added a check for `undefined`, in case an element doesn't have this style at all.

Comment: And `<` will automatically coerce it to a number.

Comment: (Removed my previous comments to reduce noise, I'll delete this one shortly.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
$('body *').css('display', function() { // don't hide the head / body / html tag
    return this.style.zIndex > 0 ? this.style.display : 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to write a filter function. Then call hide on each.

```
$("div").filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('z-index') <= 1;
}).each(function(){ $(this).hide() });
```